# iMac - 2nd display not working using thunderbolt - HDMI

Tags: imac, thunderbolt, hdmi

I recently bought an LG monitor to use as a 2nd display but my iMac (mid 2011, running Mac OS X Lion) doesn't detect it.

It's connected using a Thunderbolt-to-HDMI-cable (which I bought from The Apple Shop the other day).
What could be the cause of this bad-detection behavior?

Comment: Are you daisy-chaining any other Thunderbolt devices, or is the Thunderbolt-to-HDMI adapter plugged directly into the iMac? (if it's plugged into another Thunderbolt device, try plugging it directly into a port on the iMac)

Comment: Directly to the monitor...

Comment: directly to the monitor, yes, but directly to the iMac? As in, is there anything other than the adapter/cable between the iMac and the monitor?

Comment: no.... one cable connecting the monitor to the iMac. nothing else in between.